# Export needed output (fields in right order) from JSON file using "jq"

Tags: json, parsing, grep, jq

I try to grep needed fields and parameters from json file with jq. There is json file:

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "1.11.11.111",
    "services": [
      {
        "port": 22,
        "service_name": "SSH",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "port": 888,
        "service_name": "HTTP",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "port": 999,
        "service_name": "FTP",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "port": 17000,
        "service_name": "UNKNOWN",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "location": {
      "continent": "Europe",
      "country": "France",
      "country_code": "FR",
      "city": "Cagnes-sur-Mer",
      "postal_code": "06800",
      "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
      "province": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 43.6627,
        "longitude": 7.1545
      },
      "registered_country": "France",
      "registered_country_code": "FR"
    },
    "autonomous_system": {
      "asn": 3215,
      "description": "France Telecom - Orange",
      "bgp_prefix": "2.15.0.0/16",
      "name": "France Telecom - Orange",
      "country_code": "FR"
    },
    "operating_system": {
      "uniform_resource_identifier": "cpe:2.3:o:*:linux:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
      "part": "o",
      "product": "linux",
      "source": "OSI_TRANSPORT_LAYER"
    }
  },
  {
    "ip": "2.22.22.222",
    "services": [
      {
        "port": 4444,
        "service_name": "HTTP",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "port": 8085,
        "service_name": "HTTP",
        "transport_protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "location": {
      "continent": "Europe",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "city": "Scunthorpe",
      "postal_code": "DN16",
      "timezone": "Europe/London",
      "province": "England",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 53.5651,
        "longitude": -0.6375
      },
      "registered_country": "United Kingdom",
      "registered_country_code": "GB"
    },
    "autonomous_system": {
      "asn": 12576,
      "description": "EE Ltd",
      "bgp_prefix": "2.25.0.0/16",
      "name": "EE Ltd",
      "country_code": "GB"
    }
  }
]
```

So, I want to select HTTP ports of each ip, and output in that format:

```
1.11.11.111:888
2.22.22.222:4444
2.22.22.222:8085
```

I tried to do next commands:

```
jq '.[].ip, .[].services[0].port, .[].services[0].service_name'
```

but I received:

```
"1.11.11.111"
"2.22.22.222"
"3.33.33.333"
6001
22
4444
3333
2082
80
80
9180
"HTTP"
"SSH"
"HTTP"
"FTP"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```sh
jq -r '.[] | .ip + ":\(.services[] | select(.service_name == "HTTP") | .port)"'
```

```
1.11.11.111:888
2.22.22.222:4444
2.22.22.222:8085
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZK1U7svFdU)